# Entity Framework: PrimaryKey-Property "Name" of class T overides/hides Property "T.Name"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity class "XY".

```
public class XY
{
    [Key]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<JJ> jj {get; set;}

    public class JJ
    {
        public string Name{get; set;}
    }
}
```

If I save an object of XY with an object JJ in the database for example by

```
DbContext context = new DbContext();
XY xy = new XY(){Name = "XY"};
xy.jj.Add(new JJ(){Name = "JJ");
context.SaveChanges();
```

then the jj.Name Property returns "XY" instead of the expected string "JJ".
Could someone explain me what's going on there and how I can use again the JJ.Name Property?

Comment: Why is JJ defined inside XY? What is the relationship of XY and JJ?

Comment: Please correct the case of the variables (`XY` to `xy`). Also, explain how to access `jj.Name` in a complete case.

Comment: Did you try `xy.jj.Name`?

Comment: This is weird declaration for EF. also, you need to use `KeyAttribute -ForeignKeyAttrribute` to establish relations

Comment: Whether class JJ is contained or not in XY doesn't matter. xy.jj.Name returns the same.
I will try this with the KeyAttribute -ForeignKeyAttribute.